# Jenkins cps groovy does not catch NoSuchMethodError exceptions

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Is there anyway to catch NoSuchMethodError errors when the groovy code calls a method which doesn't exist?

The following code causes a NoSuchMethodError error which is not caught but the finally block does execute.  This causes problems for some of my error handling and reporting.

#### Code with bogus dsl

```
try {
    println "in try"
    dslDoesNotExist()
} catch (Exception ex) {
    println "Caught error ${ex}"
    throw ex
} finally {
    println "finally block"
}
```

#### Result

```
in try
[Pipeline] echo
finally block    // see the finally but not the catch
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'dslDoesNotExist'
```

If I modify the code about to reference a property/variable that does not exist the catch block is processed

#### Code with missing property

```
try {
    println "in try"
    propertyOrVariableDoesNotExist
} catch (Exception ex) {
    println "Caught error ${ex}"
    throw ex
} finally {
    println "finally block"
}
```

#### Result

```
in try
[Pipeline] echo
Caught error groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: propertyOrVariableDoesNotExist for class: WorkflowScript
[Pipeline] echo
finally block
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: propertyOrVariableDoesNotExist for class:
```

## What is going on here

### Java vs Groovy Exceptions?

Can CPS groovy catch(Exception ex) catch java.lang. exceptions?  No

#### Code

```
    try {
        throw new java.lang.NoSuchMethodError("dsl problem")
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        println "Caught"
    }
```

#### Result

```
    // No evidence of the catch
    
    [Pipeline] { (hide)
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // node
    [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: dsl problem
```

Comment: What is the context for this code? Is it a library, global var, script block, or native scripted DSL? Where would you expect the method to be defined normally? Note also you are attempting to catch a Java exception within Groovy in the first unsuccessful example, and a Groovy exception within Groovy in the second successful example.

Comment: The context is that the code loads groovy code from another repo.  If the repo branch chosen lacked the method, then we'd hit this problem.  I thought a catch would catch everything but that's not true

Comment: I also tried catch(java.lang.NoSuchMethodError){...} which didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @jeff-scott-brown as he was right.  It took some digging and experimentation to figure this out.  I was mistaken.

The ancestry of [NoSuchMethodError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html) looks like

```
 java.lang.Object
    java.lang.Throwable
        java.lang.Error
            java.lang.LinkageError
                java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
                    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
```

The ancestry of [Groovy Exception](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.7/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/GroovyException.html) is

```
java.lang.Throwable
    java.lang.Exception
        org.codehaus.groovy.GroovyException
```

So, if I refactor the code to this it works as expected.  When I initially tested this, I hit a security sandbox error which obfuscated the results and I missed it (it was glaring so I don't know how I missed it, but I did)

### Code

```
try {
    dslNotExist()
} catch (java.lang.Throwable ex) {
    println "Caught"
}
```

### Result

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
Caught
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
```